# Surface had no valid native Surface for Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-textureview

I've integrated camera2 with textureVIew. It works on all devices but on tablet when we capture image for first time, it crashesand displays following logs.

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface had no valid native Surface.
           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.nativeGetSurfaceId(LegacyCameraDevice.java)
           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceId(LegacyCameraDevice.java:658)
           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.containsSurfaceId(LegacyCameraDevice.java:678)
           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager$2.onPictureTaken(RequestThreadManager.java:220)
           at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1248)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim$CameraLooper.run(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:136)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Following code is used to capture the image.

```
 protected void takePicture() {
        if (getContext() == null || cameraDevice == null) return;

        lockFocus();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            if (characteristics != null) {
                sizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }

            ImageReader reader = getImageReader();
            if (reader == null) return;

            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = getSurfaces(reader);
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = getCaptureBuilder(reader);

            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788777/camera2-api-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-surface-had-no-valid-native-sur

Comment: @DarshanPania That solution is not working.

Comment: Could you add some code to your question to help understand what happens when the camera captures an image goes back?

Comment: @DarshanPania - I've added code. kindly check.

Comment: What is this **getSurfaces(** *ImageReader* **)** ? It could return something wrong for legacy camera2. When your camera `CameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY`, you may find it easier to capture JPEG using the *deprecated* Camera API. On older devices, **camera2** may have some glitches that are very hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

That can happen if the ImageReader gets garbage collected before the camera picture capture completes.

Does the getImageReader method store the image reader somewhere permanent (like as a class member)? If not, the Surface from the ImageReader is like a weak reference, and will not keep it from being removed.